# Filter Child Tags Values

Tags: php, html, dom

How to filter child tags value of a `<div>` and display just the parent inner texts?
For example in this code :

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$htm='<div class="date">
         <span class="title">post date <!-- or Anything --> :</span>
         2103/04/07 13:06
      </div>';

$html = str_get_html($htm);    

$date = $html->find('.date ',0)->plaintext;

echo $date;
```

The result is :

```
post date : 2103/04/07 13:06
```

But I need :

```
2103/04/07 13:06
```

Is there any way to filter the `<span>` values? I prefer to not use patterns in my case.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possibly not the cleanest solution, but it works:

```
$dateDiv = $html->find('.date', 0);
$textElems = $dateDiv->find('text');

$str = '';
foreach ($textElems as $subText) {
    if ($subText->parent() === $dateDiv) {
        $str .= $subText->plaintext;
    }
}
echo $str;
```

It retrieves all text blocks and then removes all nodes which are not direct children of `<div class="date">`.